# Getting 400 error when trying to get auth token - twitter omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, twitter-oauth

I've got a rails app in which I am trying to implement twitter omniauth so many users can post/get to/from many twitter accounts from within the app. I have followed the [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth-revised) (until about 3 minutes in) on the topic exactly yet am getting a 400 http response.

In my gemfile:

```
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
```

In `/config/initializers/omniauth.rb`

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :twitter, ENV['TWITTER_KEY'], ENV['TWITTER_SECRET'],
end
```

In my view I naturally have  `<%= link_to "Connect", "/auth/twitter" %>` and in my `routes.rb` I have (this is the only difference to the railscast as I am not using it to signup/login users but rather to post to twitter):

```
get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'twitter_accounts#create'
get 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
```

Clicking the link in the view results in the following error:

```
OAuth::Unauthorized
400 Bad Request
```

As far as I can see my api key & secret are correct so it seems that it is not setting the http header correctly. The request and response params are empty on the rails error page. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

So as usual after tearing my hair out all day I got it to work the minute I post the question here. The issue was it was not picking up my environment variables. I had pasted in the strings directly to see if this was the problem however this also **required a restart of the rails app** to take effect which I had not done.

Answer (score 1):

Just to extend on the answer of rorykoehler, you may also need to restart your terminal for it to pick up the environmental variables of your OAuth key and secret. If you have them stored in your bash profile you can just run

```
    source ~/.bash_profile
```

in your terminal for it to pick it up.
If you are running your code in an IDE like RubyMine or Visual Studio Code you may need to restart your IDE.

Answer (score -2):

Just change

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :twitter, ENV['TWITTER_KEY'], ENV['TWITTER_SECRET'],
end
```

with

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :twitter, 'TWITTER_KEY', 'TWITTER_SECRET'
end
```

Comment: Storing keys/secrets in environment variables is recommended over checking them into version control. This may technically work for a development environment; a better answer would be how to actually pick up your environment variables in this scope.